# paginate merged collections (or: how to sort by presence of a string)

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I originally had this solution for searching for a term:

```
Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$searched.'%')->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%'.$searched.'%')->paginate(100);
```

### What I want:

I want the records containing a term in title to be on top of the colllection

#### My temporary solution:

Pretty obvious:

```
$posts1 = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$searched.'%')->paginate(100);
$posts2 = Post::where('content', 'LIKE', '%'.$searched.'%')->paginate(100);

$object = $posts1->merge($posts2);
```

### Problem to solve

The `$object` collection cannot be paginated. I get error `Method hasPages does not exist.`.
Is there any way to keep the pagination function on the resulting (sorted & merged) collection?

Comment: why not use `union` instead? just union those 2 select query https://gyazo.com/a94c16f4e8683c7d0def54cde18c5899

Comment: Same error: `Method hasPages does not exist.`

Comment: that error occur when you use `union`?

Comment: No, sorry, wrobgly pasted. When using your solution I get `SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns (SQL: (select count(*) as aggregate from `posts` where `content` LIKE %konf%) union (select * from `posts` where `title` LIKE %konf%))`

Comment: can you screen shot(show) your updated code. also when you union query it must have same number of columns specified on it

Comment: It is exactly the same as the "temporary solution" in my question.

Comment: it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56142421/6901246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use

```
->orderByRaw()
```

them using

```
'(case when title LIKE "%'.$searched.'%" then 1 else 2 end) ASC'
```

in this cause those whose name contains `$searched` will be on the top

so your query builder would be like this

```
Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$searched.'%')
->orWhere('content', 'LIKE', '%'.$searched.'%')
->orderByRaw('(case when title LIKE "%'.$searched.'%" then 1 else 2 end) ASC')
->paginate(100);
```

Comment: your answer seem extremely promising, but I dont know how to fix syntax. If I use your code, I get `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '(when name LIKE "%konf%" then 1 else 2)' in 'order clause' `

Comment: This gives me syntax error: `->orderByRaw("CASE WHEN title LIKE %konf% THEN 1 else 2 END ASC")` Any hint? (Note: I have hard-written the search term to simplify debugging.) The error says: `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax...`

Comment: @Peter ops I forgot to add 'case'  at the beginning of orderByRaw. and add 'end' at the end

Comment: I corrected it myself. Still I have the syntax error. I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: @Peter what's the error? I tested this query builder and it doesn't generate any error

Comment: It is the `Syntax error or access violation: 1064` I mention above. Might be related to my MySQL version: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.16 (On Ubuntu)

Comment: @Peter let's continue here. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129500/paginate-merged-collections-or-how-to-sort-by-presence-of-a-string