# How to paginate a collection after get() in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pagination

I have a merge on two query results which works fine:

```
$events1 = \App\Event::Where('valid_to','>=',$today)->orderByRaw('valid_to','ASC')->get();
$events2 = \App\Event::Where('valid_to','<',$today)>orderByRaw('valid_to','ASC')->get();
$events = $events1->merge($events2);
```

Now I need to paginate this new collection and as suggestted I added this piece:

```
$page = 1;
$perPage = 60;
$pagination = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator(
    $events->forPage($page, $perPage), 
    $events->count(), 
    $perPage, 
    $page
);
```

EDIT: For future readers, patricus's answer works great and I did that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're calling `links()` and `render()` on the wrong object. You've assigned the paginator to the `$pagination` variable. You should be calling

```
$pagination->links()
```

or

```
$pagination->render()
```

Also, if you'd like to clean this up a little bit, you can modify your query so that you only have one query and don't need to combine two different result sets. You just need to first order on the result of the date comparison, and then order on your `valid_to` field.

```
$events = \App\Event::orderByRaw('valid_to < ?', [$today])->orderBy('valid_to')->get();
```

The date comparison will return a true/false result. In ASC order (default when not specified), `true` results will come after `false` results, so rows where the `valid_to` is less than `$today` (expired) will come after the rows where `valid_to` is greater than or equal to `$today`.

That result set will then be ordered by the `valid_to` field itself. This one query gives you the same results as the two queries you've manually merged. And, of course, you can just paginate this one query:

```
$events = \App\Event::orderByRaw('valid_to < ?', [$today])->orderBy('valid_to')->paginate(60);
```

Now, it is your `$events` object that is paginated, so you would want to use `$events->links()` and `$events->render()`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I did that and as long as the $page = 1 it works but when I put $page =2 to debug something goes wrong and I get "Trying to get property of non-object (View:... " At the moment I am trying to find which non-object cause the problem.

Answer (score 15):

best way for paginate collection:

1- add this to boot function in \app\Providers\AppServiceProvider

```
  /**
         * Paginate a standard Laravel Collection.
         *
         * @param int $perPage
         * @param int $total
         * @param int $page
         * @param string $pageName
         * @return array
         */
        Collection::macro('paginate', function($perPage, $total = null, $page = null, $pageName = 'page') {
            $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);
            return new LengthAwarePaginator(
                $this->forPage($page, $perPage),
                $total ?: $this->count(),
                $perPage,
                $page,
                [
                    'path' => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
                    'pageName' => $pageName,
                ]
            );
        });
```

2-From hereafter for all collection you can paginate like this

```
$events1 = \App\Event::Where('valid_to','>=',$today)->orderByRaw('valid_to','ASC')->get();
$events2 = \App\Event::Where('valid_to','<',$today)>orderByRaw('valid_to','ASC')->get();
$events = $events1->merge($events2); 

$events->paginate(5)
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked perfectly for me

Comment: I see a lot of comments saying "wHy WouLd You Evr Need To PaGinaTe Aftr Get?!" on a lot of posts when trying to figure out how to do this - 

Its very simple - We have a view with a table of paginated data that has statistics generated off of the same search results. So instead of running the same query TWICE - one to gather paginated results and the second to go through and map/filter/sort into various statistics ( breakdown by category, by work done by user, etc ) I can now just do the query ONCE, map all of the necessary stats, and then paginated the collection to return for the UI