# laravel keep pagination after collection merge

Tags: laravel

i need to keep pagination after merge differt collection, the collection have the same structure.

**code**

```
 $allclients = collect();

 foreach($User as $user){
       $clients = Users::where('status', 'LIKE', $stat.'%')->orderBy('name')->paginate($this->pagination);
       if($allclients->isEmpty()){
                $allclients = $clients;
       }
       $allclients = $allclients->merge($clients);
 }
```

When i use merge() my pagination disappear.

Comment: it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56142421/6901246

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have changed $stat into array(), removing the foreach

```
 $clients = Users::whereIn('status', $stat)->orderBy('name')->paginate($this->pagination);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$clients = Users::where('status', 'LIKE', $stat.'%')->orderBy('name')->paginate($this->pagination);
$clients = collect($clients->items());
$allclients = $allclients->merge($clients);
```

Comment: Have you collect  $allclients data??