# Laravel Collection Pagination

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to paginate a collection, however I'm struggling to figure out if there's an easier way to do this.

I have added the following macro in my `AppServiceProvider`:

```
Collection::macro('paginate', function($perPage) {
    $page = request()->page ?: 0;

    $slice = $this->chunk($perPage)[$page > 0 ? $page - 1 : 0];

    return new LengthAwarePaginator($slice, $this->count(), $perPage, $page, [
        'path' => url()->current(),
    ]);
});
```

This seems to be working for now, but I'm wondering if this will do in the long run? Is it possible to paginate the results before they become a collection? For example, here's how I get the collection I'm trying to paginate:

In my repository I have:

```
private function eagerLoadQuotes()
{
    return Quote::with([
        'user', 
        'home', 
        'home.customer', 
        'installation', 
        'installation.commission', 
        'installation.preInstallationSurvey', 
        'installation.jobSheet'
    ]);
}

public function unstarted()
{
    return $this->eagerLoadQuotes()->find(
            Installation::doesntHave('preInstallationSurvey')
            ->pluck('quote_id')
        );
}

private function mine($collection)
{
    return $collection->filter(function ($item, $key) {
        return $item->user_id == auth()->user()->id;
    });
}

public function myUnstarted()
{
    return $this->mine($this->unstarted());
}
```

and then I get that in my controller:

```
public function myUnstarted()
{
    $quotes = $this->installations->myUnstarted();

    return view('installations.viewAll', compact('quotes'));
}
```

There are a number of other methods too which reuse the private methods.

Comment: Why don't you use the `->paginate()` method on the `Builder` class? I.e. `Quote::paginate(50);` The internal logic for that is using offsets when querying the data, well before it becomes a `Collection`. Your current approach will have speed issues for large datasets; pulling every record into a `Collection` then calling `->chunk()` (via `->paginate()`) has to deal with the overhead of actually getting the records from the DB.

Comment: @TimLewis I tried that and it just comes back with `Method paginate does not exist`

Comment: If you call `->paginate()` after `->pluck()`/`->filter()`, then yes, it won't work. `->filter()` should also be replaced with `->where("user_id", "=", auth()->user()->id)`.

Comment: I'll edit my main post to include my actual code, as opposed to the inline I hoped would make it easier to read. I'm struggling to figure this out.

Comment: Well that's a lot of abstraction... You're converting your `Builder` instance (`Quote::with()`) using `->find()` to a `Collection` (or `Model`, not sure of the internals of `->find()`, I always use `->get()` for a `Collection` and `->first()` for a single `Model`), then to a `Collection` using `->filter()`, so the Builder's version of `->paginate()` wouldn't be available after `->find()` and `->filter()`. Might require some reworking, using non-closure methods to keep your `Builder` intact until you can call `->paginate()`.

Comment: it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56142421/6901246

Answer (score 1):

Someone created this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/vluzrmos/3ce756322702331fdf2bf414fea27bcb) which I think will solve your issue.

Previous answers would work on Resultset collections and I think you are asking about `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. If that's the case, please refer to linked Gist, it will be something like:

```
$page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);

$items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);

return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
```

In your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the [default provided pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination) by Laravel?

In you controller that return Quotes:

```
$quotes = Quote::with(['user', 'home', 'home.customer', 'installation', 'installation.commission', 'installation.preInstallationSurvey', 'installation.jobSheet'])
    ->find(Installation::doesntHave('preInstallationSurvey')->pluck('quote_id'))
    ->filter(function ($item, $key) {
        return $item->user_id == auth()->user()->id;
    }
)->paginate(10); // Number of results per page
```

Then in you view:

```
{{ $quotes->links() }}
```

This will only query the given amount of requested rows per page, instead of returning all instances of quotes and then chunking the array after that. Will provide better performance on large collections.