# Paginate Laravel Collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-collection, laravel-paginate

I have two different querys that I merge to return a collection

```
$combinados = $histMe->merge($hist)->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

And I return them this way:

```
$final = $combinados->all();
```

But this prints all the collection, how can I paginate this? The **paginate()** laravel method doesn't work with collections. And how can I controll it from the view?

Thanks!

Comment: it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56142421/6901246

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code that I wrote a long time ago:

You must use Length aware paginator:

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;


public function paginate($items, $perPage,$setDefaultOption = true, $options = [])
    {
        if($setDefaultOption){
            $options = ['path' => request()->url(), 'query' => request()->query()];
        }
        $page = Input::get('page', 1); // Get the current page or default to 1


        $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);

        return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The api has changed slightly in newer versions. To paginate a collection you now need to use forPage.

The method forPage takes two parameters:

```
forPage(int $page, int $perPage)
```

So you can do something like this in your controller:

```
...
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $combinados = $histMe->merge($hist)->sortByDesc('created_at');

    $combinados->forPage($request->get('page'), 25);
}
...
```

Comment: How do I control the pagination in the blade view?

Comment: @AlejandroParedes The pagination is controlled by the first argument and the amount of items per page is controlled by the second argument. You can return whatever you want to your blade view.  Typically the pagination is controlled by a `page` url parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function paginate($items, $perPage =1,$setDefaultOption = true, $options = [],$page = null)
{
    if($setDefaultOption){
        $options = ['path' => request()->url(), 'query' => request()->query()];
    }
    $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);


    $items = $items instanceof Collection ? $items : Collection::make($items);

    return new LengthAwarePaginator($items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page, $options);
}



 public function test(){

    $coinUsers = collect([]);
     $users = User::role('Customer')->get();
     foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user->balanceFloat > 0) {
            $coinUsers->push($user);
        }
         
    }
     $data = $this->paginate($coinUsers);

    return view('test', array(
        'users' => $data,
    ));
}
```

Perfectly working on Laravel 8 . Please try like this

Comment: use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator; 


import these working erfectly on laravel 8