# Merge two sets of data and then sort and paginate in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am running two sets of queries. But the problem is I can't sort and paginate on them. 
My code is given below.

```
$orderhenkans = Orderhenkan::where('kokyakubango',Auth::guard('web')->user()->bango)
                               ->where('kokyakuorderbango',4)
                               ->get()->pluck('bango'); 
$misyukko1 = Misyukko::whereIn('orderbango',$orderhenkans)
                             ->whereNotNull('yoyakubi')->get();

$orderhenkans = Orderhenkan::where('kokyakubango',Auth::guard('web')->user()->bango)
                              ->get()->pluck('bango');
$misyukko2 = Misyukko::whereIn('orderbango',$orderhenkans)
                               ->whereNotNull('yoyakubi')
                               ->whereDate('hanbaibukacd','<',date('Y-m-d'))->get();

$misyukkos = $misyukko1->merge($misyukko2)->orderBy('orderbango', 'desc')->paginate(15);
```

I am trying to get two collections from the same model. Both `$misyukko1` and `$misyukko2` is giving me the correct output. After that I merge them in `$misyukkos` variable.

When I try `dd($misyukkos)` it also gives me correct result. However, I can't apply orderBy and paginate like I can normally do. How can I sort and paginate my data?

It might be worth noting that Orderhenkan model has a primary key. But Misyukko doesn't.

P.S. I searched in the forum. I found some questions which are similar to mine. But the solutions didn't work for me. So please don't mark it as duplicate.

Comment: can we make a single query. if yes then it will work as paginate(15). Can you provide what sql query(data) you want to achive.

Comment: My query is something like this. If orderhenkan.kokyakuorderbango = 4 it will check only where the misyukko.yoyakubi is not null
Otherwise it will check if the date is over. 

Is it possible to merge them into one sql?

Comment: it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56142421/6901246

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can also update into single query.

```
$orderhenkans = Orderhenkan::where('kokyakubango',Auth::guard('web')->user()->bango)
                               ->where('kokyakuorderbango',4)
                               ->get()->pluck('bango'); 

$orderhenkans_2 = Orderhenkan::where('kokyakubango',Auth::guard('web')->user()->bango)
                              ->get()->pluck('bango');

$misyukkos = Misyukko::where(function($query) use ($orderhenkans, $orderhenkans_2){
    return $query->where(function($query_2) use ($orderhenkans){
        return $query_2->whereIn('orderbango',$orderhenkans)
                       ->whereNotNull('yoyakubi');
    })
    ->orWhere(function($query_2) use ($orderhenkans_2){
        return $query_2->whereIn('orderbango',$orderhenkans_2)
                        ->whereNotNull('yoyakubi')
                        ->whereDate('hanbaibukacd','<',date('Y-m-d'));
    });
})->orderBy('orderbango', 'desc')->paginate(15);
```

edited

```
$orderhenkans = Orderhenkan::where('kokyakubango',Auth::guard('web')->user()->bango)
                                   ->where('kokyakuorderbango',4)
                                   ->get()->pluck('bango'); 

    $orderhenkans_2 = Orderhenkan::where('kokyakubango',Auth::guard('web')->user()->bango)
                                  ->get()->pluck('bango');

    $misyukkos = Misyukko::where(function($query) use ($orderhenkans, $orderhenkans_2){
        return $query->where(function($query_2) use ($orderhenkans){
            return $query_2->whereIn('orderbango',$orderhenkans);
        })
        ->orWhere(function($query_2) use ($orderhenkans_2){
            return $query_2->whereIn('orderbango',$orderhenkans_2)                            
                            ->whereDate('hanbaibukacd','<',date('Y-m-d'));
        });
    })->whereNotNull('yoyakubi')->orderBy('orderbango', 'desc')->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$misyukkos = $misyukko1->merge($misyukko2);
$misyukkos->sort()->paginate(15);
```

Comment: It is giving me the following error. 'FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR) Call to a member function paginate() on array'

Answer (score 1):

You can update your query into a single query: Suggest

Try this:

```
$orderhenkans = Orderhenkan::where('kokyakubango',Auth::guard('web')->user()->bango)
                               ->where('kokyakuorderbango',4)
                               ->get()->pluck('bango'); 


$orderhenkans2 = Orderhenkan::where('kokyakubango',Auth::guard('web')->user()->bango)
                              ->get()->pluck('bango');

$misyukkos = Misyukko::where(function($query) use ($orderhenkans, $orderhenkans2){
                            $query->where(function($q) use ($orderhenkans){
                                $q->whereIn('orderbango',$orderhenkans);
                            })
                            ->orWhere(function($q) use ($orderhenkans2){
                                return $q->whereIn('orderbango',$orderhenkans2)
                                         ->whereDate('hanbaibukacd','<',date('Y-m-d')); //or \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')
                            });
                        })
                        ->whereNotNull('yoyakubi')
                        ->orderBy('orderbango', 'desc')
                        ->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
```

```php
        $misyukkos = $misyukko1->merge($misyukko2)->toArray();

        $data = array();
        $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();
        $collection = new Collection($misyukkos);
        $per_page = 5;
        $currentPageResults = $collection->slice(($currentPage-1) * $per_page, $per_page)->all();
        $data['results'] = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageResults, count($collection), $per_page);
        $data['results']->setPath($request->url());
        dd($data);
```