# Laravel eloquent merge two results and sort

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, eloquent

I have found tons of posts about this issue and yet no solution work.

Maybe its because of my laravel version. Its 5.7.

I have two results, which look like this:

```
result_a = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('user_chatmessages')
->where('from_user', $data->chat_from_user)->get();

$result_b = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('user_chatmessages')
->where('to_user', $data->chat_from_user)->get();
```

Now I merge them, which works great:

```
$merged = $result_a->merge($result_b);
$result = $merged->values()->sortByDesc('date_added');
```

**The sorting does not affect the whole result. The problem is that the sorting sorts first `result_a` and then `result_b`.**

I tried tons of different syntax variants:

```
$result = $result_a->merge($result_b)->sortBy('date_added');

$merged = $result_a->merge($result_b);
$result = $merged->sortByDesc('date_added');

$merged = $result_a->merge($result_b)->sortByDesc('date_added');
$result = $merged->all();

$result = ($result_a->merge($result_b))->sortBy('date_added');
```

Probably even more, I am sitting for quite some time on this issue already and all I find are threads where it looks super simple and people tell it works.

I also tried to sort by `ID` with the same results.

**EDIT**

The alternative solution provided by @N69S works for the case if you want to get all received and sent messages of a certain user.

But how do you get the messages between two specific users using the same approach? For example I want to get the chatmessages between the user with ID 1 and the user with ID 2 this will not work:

```
$result = DB::connection('mysql_live')
                    ->table('user_chatmessages')
                    ->where('from_user', $data->chat_from_user)
                    ->where('to_user', $data->chat_to_user)
                    ->orWhere('from_user', $data->chat_to_user)
                    ->orWhere('to_user', $data->chat_from_user)
                    ->orderBy('date_added', 'desc')
                    ->get();
```

What I am trying right now looks like this:

```
$result = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('user_chatmessages')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($from, $to) {
        $query->where('from_user', $from)->where('to_user', $to);
    })->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->where('from_user', $to)->where('to_user', $from);
    })->orderBy('date_added', 'asc')->get();
```

But I get an error: from & to are not defined.

This works perfectly:

```
$result = DB::connection('mysql_live')->table('user_chatmessages')
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('from_user', '1')->where('to_user', '2');
        })->orWhere(function ($query) {
            $query->where('from_user', '2')->where('to_user', '1');
        })->orderBy('date_added', 'asc')->get();
```

Comment: it may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56142421/6901246

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you recover all the results in one query ?

```php
result_a = DB::connection('mysql_live')
    ->table('user_chatmessages')
    ->where('from_user', $data->chat_from_user)
    ->orWhere('to_user', $data->chat_from_user)
    ->orderBy('date_added', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

or user `->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')` if you have the default timestamps fields

**EDIT**

For recovering the chat between two specific users, you need to make use of the parenthesis.

```php
result_a = DB::connection('mysql_live')
    ->table('user_chatmessages')
    ->where(function($query) use($data) {
        $query->where('from_user', $data->chat_from_user)
            ->where('to_user', $data->chat_to_user);
    })
    ->orWhere(function($query) use($data) {
        $query->where('to_user', $data->chat_from_user)
            ->where('from_user', $data->chat_to_user);
    })
    ->orderBy('date_added', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Because its gets all results and does not narrow down the from_user, especially if you want to get the chat between two specific users.

Comment: @Roman Not sure what you mean, but this answer does exactly what you want, just in a significantly more performant way.

Comment: I agree this works for this example, but it wont work if I want to get a specific chat between User with ID 1 and User with ID 2. At least it didnt work while I tried this approach (Maybe I made a mistake). I am still curious why the merge did not work here. I cant accept because this is not the answer to the question.

Comment: @Roman mind to put in your question the example that did not work ?

Comment: @N69S Ofc. I will make an EDIT soon

Comment: @N69S Now I am even more confused. it works, but its almost the same code, which I have in the edit. The only difference is you used `use($data)`. I extracted the values one step before and used `use($from, $to)`. Why in my approach it tells me the vars are not defined? By the way, thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: @N69S Nevermind, I made a super idiotic mistake... the difference is that there are 2 clauses and I added `use()` only in the first... Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the data directly without using merging like this:

```
result = DB::connection('mysql_live')
         ->table('user_chatmessages')
         ->where(function($query) use ($data){
           $query->where('from_user', $data->chat_from_user)->orWhere('to_user', $data->chat_from_user)
         })->orderBy('date_added','desc')
           ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to use two queries then you can use union.

**Sub query**

```
$subQuery = DB::connection('mysql_live')
->table('user_chatmessages')
->where('from_user', $data->chat_from_user);
```

**Add sub query by using union on main query**

```
$results = DB::connection('mysql_live')
->table('user_chatmessages')
->where('to_user', $data->chat_from_user)
->union($subQuery)                         //see
->orderBy('date_added', 'desc')            //see
->get();
```

This should work. You can use what ever queries just make union of them to avoid merge in collections and then sort by date_added